# Download com primefaces 5.3 apos migração do 5.1 não funciona

Tags: primefaces

Estou migrando do primeface 5.1 para o 5.3 . Era para ser simples, apenas mudar a versão no maven.

Mas não esta sendo bem assim

O comando p:fileDownload não funciona mais

```
<p:commandButton id="exportarArquivo" icon="ui-icon-print" value="Exportar arquivo" disabled="#{comissaoCobradorMB.isParametros()}" process="@this" > 
    <p:fileDownload value="#{comissaoCobradorMB.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Debugando aparece o seguinte erro no browse(chrome ).

Request return with error:parsererror. primefaces.js.xhrml:1

Abaixo o MB

O código é um pouco antigo mas funcionava.

Notem que é gera um relatório. Conferi e o mesmo é gerado.

```
public StreamedContent getFile() {
        geraRelatorio();
        return this.file;
    }


    private void geraRelatorio() {
        String path ;
        String nome ;
        String extensao;
        String pathReal ;
        String pathNome ;

        DateTimeFormatter fDataParaString = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
        DateTimeFormatter fDataParaStringData = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Map parametros = new LinkedHashMap();
        parametros.put("Data De" , fDataParaStringData.format(getDataInicial()));       //fDataParaString.format(this.getDataDe()) ) ;  
        parametros.put("Data Ate", fDataParaStringData.format(getDataFinal()));         // fDataParaString.format(this.getDataDe()) );

        extensao = "."+this.getTipoArquivo();
        path = "/WEB-INF/temporarios";
        nome = "comissaoCob";
        nome+="_De_"+fDataParaString.format(this.getDataInicial());
        nome+="_Ate_"+fDataParaString.format(this.getDataFinal());
        nome+="_Gr_";

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)facesContext.getExternalContext().getContext();
        pathReal  = servletContext.getRealPath(path);

        nome = Texto.nomePadrao(pathReal, nome, extensao);

        GeraArquivoTipo geraArquivoTipo;
        if(this.getTipoArquivo().trim().equals("PDF")){
            System.out.println(".............Entrou no PDF");
            geraArquivoTipo = GeraArquivoTipo.PDF;
        } else {
            geraArquivoTipo = GeraArquivoTipo.EXCEL;
            System.out.println(".............Entrou no Excel");
        }

        new RelatorioDeComissaoDeCobradores(comissao,pathReal.trim()+"/"+nome, parametros, geraArquivoTipo);

        pathNome = path+"/"+nome;
        InputStream stream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(pathNome);            //getResourceAsStream(path+nome);
        //this.file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/octet-stream", nome);
        this.file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,"application/pdf", nome);


    }
```

Comment: tenta colocar `ajax="false"` no botão

Comment: Funcionou 
Obrigado.

Sabes dizer o porque ocorre esse comportamento?

Comment: Eu tive problemas com o ``<p:schedule`` nessa versão 5.3 e tive que voltar ao 5.0. Vê se não quebrou mais nada na sua aplicação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml) do `Primefaces` você deve setar a propriedade Ajax do botão como false

```
ajax="false"
```

Basicamente `ajax` no `commandButton` especifica como será feito o submit da página. Você pode obter mais informações nesses links:

http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/commandButton.html
http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-ajax-com-java-server-faces-jsf/24832